# How do I make the first three of a product free in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price

Wordpress 6.2, Woocommerce 7.4, Underscore Theme

I have a product (widget) that gets automatically added to the cart if the customer chose certain other products (packages). It adds three (3) widgets to the cart and in functions.php I set the price of the widget to zero (see below) - they are normally $10.00. But the customer is allowed to add more than three widgets to the cart. How do I code this so the first three are free and the rest are full priced, and say they add two more, the cart displays Widgets(5) with a total of $20.00?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10, 1);

function add_custom_price($cart_object) {
    foreach ($cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($value['product_id'], array(21,24,26,704))) {
            if ($package_chosen == 15) { // calculated elsewhere
                $_price = 0;
            } else if ($package_chosen == 16) {
                $_price = 0;
            }
            $value['data']->set_price($_price);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone? This has to have been done before.

Comment: your question is unclear. plz provide more information

Comment: How do I set the first three of an item to $0.00 and charge the normal price after that? if they order 5 they get charged for 2.

Comment: If they order 10 they get charged for 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these codes to set free first 3 products to the cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_change_cart_items_price' );
function conditionally_change_cart_items_price( $cart_object ) {
    $_item_index = 1;
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( in_array( $_item_index, array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( 0 );
        }
        
        $_item_index ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes the first three products zero, I need the first three items of product ID 26 to be zero, then all additional items of product ID 26 to be normal price.

Comment: Say you buy a fruit basket, it comes with three free apples. Then if you add more apples they are $10,00 each. So 5 apples would be $20.00.

Comment: Is there really no way to do this?